# Adding array elements to every other element in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops, addition

I am having a problem adding each element of the array and then adding the next element in the array to the result, I have tried different ways but can't get it to work here is the code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
   int result = 0;
   int resultB = 0;
   for(int i = 0 ;i < 10; i++)
   {
      result = array[i]+array[i+1];
      resultB = result-array[i-1];
      printf("%d\n",result,resultB);
     
   }
  return 0;
  
}
```

now what I was expecting is the first 2 elements of the array like in example will be added for example: `1+2=3` then what I wanted the `result=3` to add to the second element of the array[2] i.e `3+2=5`, then `5+array[3]=8` and so on till the length of array ends. I know I am doing something wrong. How do I solve the issue?

Comment: When i equals 9, which is the last element of the array, result will try to add the value of array[10] to array[9]. This is a buffer overflow. Buffer overflows are on the list of C undefined behaviors. You must avoid undefined behaviors if you want your program to be correct.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. You have an out-of-bounds access, and `printf` printing `result` but not `resultB`.

Comment: @Unknown It is unclear what you are trying to achieve : whether you want to change elements of the array or just to output values of expressions as you described.

Answer (score 3):

When

- `i == 0` then `array[i-1]` is out of bounds
- `i == 9` then `array[i+1]` is out of bounds

These makes your program have undefined behavior.

Also, `printf("%d\n",result,resultB);` places *two* `int`s on the stack, but you only tell `printf` to use one. Either remove one or add a `%d`.

With those problems fixed:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE(x) (sizeof (x) / sizeof *(x))

int main(void) {
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int result = 0;
    int resultB = 0;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE(array) - 1; i++) {
//               ^                  ^^^
        result = array[i] + array[i + 1];
        resultB = result - array[i - 1];
        printf("%d %d\n", result, resultB);
//                 ^^
    }
}
```

The algorithm will produce this output:

```
5 4
7 5
9 6
11 7
13 8
15 9
17 10
19 11
```

Answer (score 2):

I see several problems here.

First of all, `array[i+1]` will access an undefined memory area when `i=9` (since the maximum index of `array` is `9`, accessing `array[9+1]` is clearly out of bounds).

The same happens to `array[i-1]` when `i=0`.

Keep in mind that **arrays** in **C** are **zero-based**, and that the **first element** is `0` and **last one** is `9` in your example.

Another problem is with your `printf`, you're using a **single** `%d`, but are trying to print **two** integer values. It should be `%d\t\%d\n` or something similar.

I would rewrite this as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
   int result = 0;
   int resultB = 0;

   for(int i = 1 ;i < 10; i++)
   {
      result = array[i]+array[i-1];
      resultB = result+array[i];
      printf("%d\t%d\n",result,resultB);
   }

   return 0; 
}
```

The output of this version of the code is as follows:

```
3   5
5   8
7   11
9   14
11  17
13  20
15  23
17  26
19  29
```

Comment: thanks but still not getting the expected output.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't fully understood what is the expected output. The way you explained it is a bit confusing. It would be very helpful if you add a table with the actual expected results in a sorted way.

Comment: hi please see the answer for what i mean

Answer (score 0):

array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

example the expected resulting values

array[0]+[1] = 3 //result is 3

then

result+array[1], i.e (resulting value was 3)+array[1] = 5 //this time result is 5

then

result+array[2],i.e (resulting value was 5)+array[2] = 8 //now result is 8

then

result+array[2],i.e (resulting value was 8)+array[2] = 11 //result

then

result+array[3],i.e(resulting value was 11)+array[3] = 15 // result

then

result+array[3],i.e(resulting value was 15)+array[3] = 19 // result

then

result+array[4],i.e(resulting value was 19)+array[4] = 24 //result

then

result+array[4],i.e(resulting value was 24)+array[4] = 29 // result

and so on till this end

as u can see every time the result is added then re added again to next element in array

so the out put will be:

```
5
8
11
15
19
24
29
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).